# How can I model a tilting mirror in PyZDDE?

Tags: python

I am trying to model spherical aberrations as a function of the tilt angle of a mirror in an optical system. I am using Optics Studio for the model and PyZDDE to communicate with it. I thought this would be easy; I would setup a list of tilt angles and then loop over them changing the relevant surface parameters and calling `zGetZernike()`:

```
for i in range(len(angle)):
    ln.zSetSurfaceParameter(n, 54, angle[i])
    ln.zSetSurfaceParameter(n, 64, -angle[i])
    ln.zGetZernike()
    print(Zern[1])
```

However, this didn't work.

I am getting the same Zernike coefficients independent of angle. I tried calling `ln.zPushLens(1)` and `ln.zGetUpdate()` but neither one worked. It looks like the changes are not getting updated on the server side.
I also tried introducing coordinate breaks before and after the mirror surface and changing the angles for those surfaces but that didn't work either.

What am I missing and what can be done to make this work ?

I would also like to change the wavelength, but that doesn't seem to work either. I call `ln.zSetPrimaryWave(N)`, where N is a wave number, but the server always uses the first wavelength from the settings in Optics Studio.

Is there a way to change the wavelength with which the Zernike coefficients are calculated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out changing tilts and decenters directly from surface properties using `zSetSurfaceParameter()` didn’t work. I had to use two coordinate breaks, one in front of the mirror surface and one behind it, and to set the tilts and decenters for those surfaces using `zSetSurfaceParameter()`. I chose to set a pickup solve on the second surface that restores the geometry behind the mirror and was only changing the tilts and decenters on the first surface. The parameter numbers for x tilts and y tilts are 3 and 4 correspondingly, as described in the Optics Studio manual. For debugging it really helps to push the lens to the lens editor after each change of parameters (`zPushLens(1)`). One should also consider saving intermediate configurations as Zemax design files. However for the actual calculation none of this is necessary. Also Optics Studio uses the first wavelength in the settings for the Zernike calculation. I had to change the wavelength using `zSetWave()`. Thanks to Indranil and ZEMAX technical support for valuable advice and guidance along the way.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the parameter numbers 3 and 4 (instead of 54 and 64) with the function `zSetSurfaceParameter()`.

The codes `SDAT_TILT_X_BEFORE` (54) and `SDAT_TILT_X_AFTER` (64) respectively are meant to be used with the function `zSetSurfaceData()`, which sets the appropriate fields in the `Surface Properties >> Tilt/Decenter` Tab for the specified surface in the main Zemax/OpticStudio application.

Please note that you need to use parameters 3 and 4 (with the function `zSetSurfaceParameter()`) if you are using coordinate breaks. Additionally, you may use parameter numbers 1 and 2 if the surface type is tilted.

I'm not sure why the function `zSetPrimaryWave()`is not working for you. I just tested the function in OpticStudio, and it works as expected.

Regards,
Indranil.

Comment: zSetPrimaryWave() changes the primary wave. However, for Zernike calculations Optics Studio uses the first wavelength from the settings, not the primary wave. Also parameters 1 and 2 for coordinate breaks are for decenters, not tilts, at least in the current Optics Sudio 16.5, SP3.

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess that I should have been more clear. I wanted to say that if you used a "Tilted surface" type instead of using coordinate breaks, then you would have to use parameters 1 and 2 that modifies the tangent-x and tangent-y angles of the (tilted) surface.

Comment: Good point. This should work with flat surfaces. However in my case the optical system is a telescope and the mirror is an aspheric surface with finite curvature. I guess I should have made this clearer.